# Javascript Regex to Extract a Number

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have strings such as

```
(123)abc
defg(456)
hijkl
(999)
7
```

I want to match these strings one at a time with a regular expression to extract any number from the string where the string starts with a '(' has a number in between and then a ')' followed by zero or more characters. So, in the above 5 examples I would match 123 in the first case, nothing in the second and third case, 999 in the fourth case and nothing in the fifth case.

I have tried this

```
var regex = new RegExp("^\((\d+)\)", "gm");
var matches = str.match(regex);
```

But matches always comes out as null.  What am I doing wrong?

I have tried this regex at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fA3oT7/1) and it seems to work so I am at a loss why the code doesn't work.

Comment: When using the `RegExp` constructor, you'll need to provide escape sequences for both the pattern and the string literal -- `new RegExp("^\\((\\d+)\\)", "gm")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to push the result of the capturing group to an array, for this use the `exec()` method.

```
var str = '(123)abc\ndefg(456)\nhijkl\n(999)\n7'
var re  = /^\((\d+)\)/gm, 
matches = [];

while (m = re.exec(str)) {
  matches.push(m[1]);
}

console.log(matches) //=> [ '123', '999' ]
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't see anything wrong with your regex, try this code generated from regex101:

```
var re = /^\((\d+)\)/gm; 
var str = '(123)abc\ndefg(456)\nhijkl\n(999)\n7';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/mK2hD5/1)**

Btw, as **[jonathan lonowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15031/jonathan-lonowski)** pointed in his comment you have to escape backslashes when you use RegExp:

```
new RegExp("^\\((\\d+)\\)", "gm")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
var regex = /^\((\d+)(?=\))/gm;
```

and use captured group #1

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uE7dQ0/1)

Using regex constructor (note double escaping):

```
var regex = new RegExp("^\\((\\d+)(?=\\))", "gm");
```